# How to get the newest data from database in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with these column :

```
id|company_id|company_name|create_at|updated_at|deleted_at
```

For example in mydatabase now, I already have 5 data. Then I just want to take 3 newest data from my database. What command should I use? Right now I'm just using

```
$comIn = new CompanyInfo;
$modalData = $comIn->where('company_id',$cid)->get();
```

`$modalData` contains all of the five data available, actually I can create another variable to put the last 3 data from `$modalData`. But I just want to do it by mysql command, Could I really do that ? What should I put in where

`('company_id,$cid, bla bla bla bla bla...??)->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this it will do the work

```
$comIn = new CompanyInfo;
$modalData = $comIn->where('company_id',$cid)->orderBy('id','desc')->take(3)->get();
```